# How to invoke viewcomponent syncrounous

Tags: razor-pages

I see examples of invoking a viewcomponent like this within a razorpage

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("PriorityList", new { maxPriority = 4, isDone = true })
```

The docs also mention there is an synchronous method Invoke, but I cant find an example of using it.  When I try to use Component.Invoke, I get this

> 'IViewComponentHelper' does not contain a definition for 'Invoke' and
>   no accessible extension method 'Invoke' accepting a first argument of
>   type 'IViewComponentHelper' could be found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docs also discuss how to perform synchronous work in a ViewComponent. Your component class will include a synchronous Invoke method, but you still call it using await:

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("PriorityList", new { maxPriority = 4, isDone = true })
```

> The method signature of PriorityList.Invoke is synchronous, but Razor
>   finds and calls the method with Component.InvokeAsync in the markup
>   file.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-3.0#perform-synchronous-work